# how to connect circles with line vertically if clicked on circle it should fill with color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create structure as shown in the image below with unordered list item if user click on the list item the circle should fill with color. i have created on div inside that i have took list items and inside list span element.I user clicks on first list item the circle should fill with color if i click on another list then it should fill with color just like active or focus on links in menubar

Here is what i have to achieve
[Here is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6zee.jpg)

Here what i have tried

```
    <div class="sizes">
    <ul>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>6"x6" | 599</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x12" | 799</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x18" | 999</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>18"x12" | 799</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>16"x20" | 1,399</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.shop-all .product-content ul li {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;}

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span {
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #d95d5d;
      padding: 2px 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color:#fff;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span.filled {
        background-color: #d95d5d;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span:before{
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      border-left:1px solid #d95d5d;
      top:10px;
      z-index: -1;
      height: 92%;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child span:before{
     content:none;
    }
     .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child{
      padding-bottom:0
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

jquery

```
$('.dot').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('filled');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```js
$('.dot').on('click', function(){

$(this).toggleClass("filled");
$(this).siblings().removeClass("filled");

});
```

```css
    body { margin:0; padding:0;}
  
   .container {width: 600px;}
  
   .shop-all .product-content ul li {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer; line-height:16px;}

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span {
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #d95d5d;
      padding: 0 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color:#fff;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li.filled span {
        background-color: #d95d5d;
    }
 

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span:before{
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      border-left:1px solid #d95d5d;
      top:10px;
      z-index: -1;
      height: 92%;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child span:before{
     content:none;
    }
     .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child{
      padding-bottom:0
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-all">
 <div class="product-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>6"x6" | 599</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x12" | 799</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x18" | 999</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>18"x12" | 799</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>16"x20" | 1,399</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to add class on html as per css and use below jquery

```js
$('.dot').on('click', function(){
  $('.dot').children('span').removeClass('filled');
  $(this).children('span').toggleClass('filled');
});
```

```css
.shop-all .product-content ul li {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;}

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span {
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #d95d5d;
      padding: 2px 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color:#fff;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span.filled {
        background-color: #d95d5d;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span:before{
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      border-left:1px solid #d95d5d;
      top:10px;
      z-index: -1;
      height: 92%;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child span:before{
     content:none;
    }
     .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child{
      padding-bottom:0
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-all">
 <div class="product-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>6"x6" | 599</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x12" | 799</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x18" | 999</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>18"x12" | 799</li>
      <li class="dot"><span></span>16"x20" | 1,399</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery("li").click(function() {
   jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
   jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
  });
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0;}
  
  .container {
   width: 600px;
  }
  
  .shop-all .product-content ul li {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer; line-height:16px;}

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span {
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #d95d5d;
      padding: 0 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color:#fff;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li.active span {
        background-color: #d95d5d;
    }
 .shop-all .product-content ul li.active { color: #d95d5d;}

    .shop-all .product-content ul li span:before{
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      border-left:1px solid #d95d5d;
      top:10px;
      z-index: -1;
      height: 92%;
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child span:before{
     content:none;
    }
     .shop-all .product-content ul li:last-child{
      padding-bottom:0
    }

    .shop-all .product-content ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="shop-all">
            <div class="product-content">
                <ul>
                  <li class="dot"><span></span>6"x6" | 599</li>
                  <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x12" | 799</li>
                  <li class="dot"><span></span>12"x18" | 999</li>
                  <li class="dot"><span></span>18"x12" | 799</li>
                  <li class="dot"><span></span>16"x20" | 1,399</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created `filled` class for span you have to try the following way. So change

```
$('.dot').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('filled');
});
```

To

```
 $('.dot').on('click', function(){
      $('.dot').find('span').removeClass('filled');
      $(this).find('span').toggleClass('filled');
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Loa8h21r/2/)

Comment: Please use StackSnippets for HTML/CSS/JS demos.

Comment: thanks for the help but if  want to remove that filled class from current item and move it to another list which is clicked currently

Comment: @ScottSauyet sorry i am not familier with that.

Comment: @Kiranramchandran: see this meta answer for more information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/